# Get "Image Media Type" equivalent of "Places (Search) API" from "Geocoding and Search API v7 service"

Tags: here-api

I am interested in getting images for a place. I found that the `Image Media Type` from `Places (Search) API` can provide this data, as documented [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics_api/media-type-image.html).

But `Places (Search) API` also mentions that it is `In Maintenance` and that `Note: This service is no longer being actively developed. We will only provide critical fixes for this service in future. Instead, you can use the new Geocoding and Search API v7 service.`

I couldn't find anything equivalent of `Image Media Type` in `Geocoding and Search API v7 service`.

1. Did I miss something in the `Geocoding and Search API v7 service` [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/index.html) about getting images for a place?
2. If not, then should we still consume images from `Places (Search) API` or are there any other guidance/alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image media type` is only available for automotive customer in case of `Geocoding and Search API v7 service` and you can continue using `Places (Search) API` .